# find the interior/boundary/limit of set and is it open? compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $ A = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} | 5 < x < 7 \}, B = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} | 6 < x < 8\}, C = \{ 0,1,2,.....\}$ Define $S = A \cup B \cup C$.
Find the interior points of S, boundary points of S, and the limit points of S. Is the set S open? is it compact? Give explanations, formal proof not necessary.

I answered this question as follows:

$S = ((5,7) \cap  \mathbb{Q}) \cup ((6,8) \cap \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \cup \mathbb{N}$

although not asked, I identified the isolated points to be $ \mathbb{N} \setminus \{5,6,7,8\}$ which was incorrect. what is the correct answer?

limit points: $[5,8]$ was correct answer

interior points: $(6,7)$ correct answer

boundary points: $S \setminus (6,7)$ was incorrect answer, what is the correct answer?

I said the set is open, this was incorrect. Is it closed because it is countable? it is not clear to me how to justify an answer for this.

I said that it was compact, because it is possible to find a subsequence that is finite in S.  This was incorrect not sure how to justify an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set is open if it is equal to its interior, and $S$ is not equal to its interior, so it is not open. On the other hand, that does **not** mean that the set is closed, as a set can also be neither open nor closed.

For the isolated points, maybe you lost points because $0$ is also an isolated point, but it is unclear whether $0\in\mathbb N$. Either way, the isolated points are $0,1,2,3,4,9,10,11,\dots$. There are no other isolated points, as all points on $[5,8]$ clearly have neighborhoods that intersect with $S$.

For boundary points, the boundary points are the points that are in the closure of the set but not in the interior of the set, so for exmaple, $10$ is also a boundary point.